# Не запускается jar-файл из командной строки

Tags: java, jar

Собирала проект с помощью Maven в Intellij IDE.
При запуске с командной строки такая вот ошибка:

```
 C:\Users\Yulia\IdeaProjects\Maven2\target>java -jar proficio-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
 test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities
    at TestCD.main(TestCD.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Вот Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Class-Path: commons-collections-3.2.1.jar jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.
jar cssparser-0.9.16.jar httpmime-4.4.1.jar commons-logging-1.2.jar s
elenium-ie-driver-2.47.1.jar jna-platform-4.1.0.jar jna-4.1.0.jar jun
it-4.11.jar selenium-remote-driver-2.47.1.jar selenium-java-2.47.1.ja
r selenium-api-2.47.1.jar xml-apis-1.4.01.jar cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar x
alan-2.7.2.jar htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar selenium-leg-rc-2.47.1.jar h
ttpcore-4.4.1.jar serializer-2.7.2.jar selenium-support-2.47.1.jar co
mmons-io-2.4.jar guava-18.0.jar websocket-api-9.2.11.v20150529.jar co
mmons-codec-1.10.jar websocket-common-9.2.11.v20150529.jar httpclient
-4.4.1.jar selenium-safari-driver-2.47.1.jar htmlunit-2.17.jar common
s-lang3-3.4.jar selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.47.1.jar selenium-firefox-
driver-2.47.1.jar webbit-0.4.14.jar gson-2.3.1.jar selenium-chrome-dr
iver-2.47.1.jar nekohtml-1.9.22.jar websocket-client-9.2.11.v20150529
.jar xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar jetty-io-9.2.11.v20150529.jar commons-exec
-1.3.jar netty-3.5.2.Final.jar sac-1.3.jar hamcrest-core-1.3.jar sele
nium-edge-driver-2.47.1.jar

Main-Class: TestCD
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.devzuz.mvnbook.proficio</groupId>
<artifactId>proficio</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <testng.version>6.8.17</testng.version>
    <selenium.version>2.47.1</selenium.version>
    <compiler.version>1.7</compiler.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>TestCD</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
```

Comment: Покажите манифест proficio-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar там должен быть объявлен класспас. Похоже что у вас не хватает зависимостей или они лежат не там

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего в pom.xml нет зависимости, в которой находится `org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities`
Проверьте библиотеки и пересоберите проект.

Comment: тогда бы не собралось. зависимость есть, но она может быть optional. Скорее всего манифест не правильно собирается.